# display video frames in an ASP.NET Core Razor Page with byte [] array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, rtsp-client

I'm trying to display the byte [] array that is taken from the RtspClientSharp.dll into an `<img>` tag (HTML), but this only works when the page in loading (ASP.NET). What I´m trying to do is to display every frame as faster as the user can watch the video from an IP camera.

The way I use to set the image URL is
`String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(viewer.imageBytes))`

Here is the code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@{
    CameraViewer viewer = new CameraViewer("192.168.0.65"); 
    viewer.Start();      
 }   

<div class="veiwer">  
    @while(!viewer.isDisplayed){}
    @{String imgUrl=String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(viewer.imageBytes));}
    <img  src="@imgUrl"/>        
</div>
```

I have tried using JavaScript too, but it doesn't works.